# Changing customer path to checkout in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, php

I'm quite new to magento development and would like some advice regarding product upsells. I have a requirement to change the path to checkout by offering products to the customer once the have added an item to their basket.

The upsell will be based on a yes/no whereby if the customer clicks yes the item is add to their basket and they are presented with another upsell.

If they click no they also presented with items before checking out. I know Magento handles upsells very differently from what i have just explained but is there a way to do this?

I really would like just a starting point of which files to edit etc... Thankyou!

Comment: These are modeled as/called crosssells in Magento.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have managed to integrate something.